# When should I think about upgrading our RDS MySQL instance based on memory usage?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

It seems like our DB server is doing garbage collection at a increasingly faster rate, which seem normal since it's growing. What's a good rule of thumb of when to switch to a bigger instance, I'm not a DBA and have no frame of reference. It seems to be doing garbage collection once every 2-3 days now whenever there's only 100mb left.

[image]

The server itself has 1.7GB of RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran across this question, and can give you a couple of suggestions.

If you're trying to gauge when to move to a bigger instances (vs. increasing the size of the databases) when you're getting close to hitting some sort of resource limit:  Memory, I/O and CPU all have the ability to limit your performance.

The symptom you mention in the question may be a symptom that you're using more and more memory - memory used for cache & buffers are being reclaimed for other uses.  Upgrading to a large instance type will increase the amount of available memory.

The chart that Rolando posted should give you a good guideline as to the number of available connections - if you're hitting those limits, then it's time to upgrade.  Available connections are directly related to available memory, so hitting connection limits means you should upgrade.

If your CPU is averaging > 50% or so, you might want to start planning on an upgrade.

Finally, if you see consistently high I/O you may want to consider a larger instance (generally, the more powerful the instance the better the I/O) or using provisioned IOPS.

Answer (score 4):

Before you switch server models, you need to know what differences there in configuration

I sat down and carefully looked over all default MySQL settings that would normally be written in a my.cnf. All are values are the same with the exception of two

- [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)
- [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)

Amazon set the following values based on server model

```
MODEL      max_connections innodb_buffer_pool_size
---------  --------------- -----------------------
t1.micro   34                326107136 (  311M)
m1-small   125              1179648000 ( 1125M,  1.097G)
m1-large   623              5882511360 ( 5610M,  5.479G)
m1-xlarge  1263            11922309120 (11370M, 11.103G)
m2-xlarge  1441            13605273600 (12975M, 12.671G)
m2-2xlarge 2900            27367833600 (26100M, 25.488G)
m2-4xlarge 5816            54892953600 (52350M, 51.123G)
```

For more information see my past posts on MySQL in Amazon RDS

- `Sep 21, 2012` : [MySQL 5.5 Runs Out of Memory, Drops All Connections When Creating Many Databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24643/mysql-5-5-runs-out-of-memory-drops-all-connections-when-creating-many-databases/24661#24661)
- `Sep 18, 2012` : [How do I reduce the database size on AWS RDS MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24491/how-do-i-reduce-the-database-size-on-aws-rds-mysql/24492#24492)
- `Sep 10, 2012` : [Does the Amazon RDS backup/snapshot service lock tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24062/does-the-amazon-rds-backup-snapshot-service-lock-tables/24067#24067)
- `Aug 02, 2012` : [Local database vs Amazon RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21914/local-database-vs-amazon-rds/21919#21919)
- `Jul 25, 2012` : [Scaling Percona datacenters: setup and replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21491/scaling-percona-datacenters-setup-and-replication/21498#21498)

Comment: It doesn't seem like this answers my question. I'm trying to understand when garbage collection and memory usage becomes a problem, not so much how to deal with it. I don't currently know if the garbage collection the DB is doing once every 2-3 days is healthy and at what time I should be concerned it's unhealthy, I would like to have some idea before it actually becomes an issue. How to fiddle with settings to free up memory seems like a separate issue, although I welcome the suggestions.

Comment: @KitSunde I think Rolando is indirectly trying to answer what you aren't asking - the title says "when should I upgrade" and he's basically saying upgrading won't address the memory issue, I think (though I am not a SME on this topic)

Comment: @JNK Where does it say that upgrading isn't going to solve a memory issue? It's saying "here's some things you should know about RDS". I'm not stating I have a memory issue right now, my question is about finding out how to judge when to upgrade something before it's a problem. I could calculate when it'll spend more time garbage collecting than doing any actual work and find a sweet spot for upgrading (or tuning) my server, but I'm sure someone with more experience would have a simpler way of judging these things. I'm not sure if my question is unclear, I'll happily take edit suggestions.